# Products autochanged their id's

Tags: magento-1.7, product, url

a strange thing happened to the website. Without any human intervention, a huge number of products (or maybe all of them) changed their id numbers. So now all the items open in different URL address. We discovered it, because lots of Crawl Errors started to appear in Google Webmaster.
For example let's take this ULR which appears to be not found.

http://www.jewelsberry.com/angelfish-charm-pendant-14k-gold-23854.html

If we search it in Google we can open a cached versión of the page. So this product is DZ-631. Angelfish Charm Pendant 14k Gold.
Then searching DZ-631 in catalog we find out that this ítem is existing, but somehow has different id, so it opens in different address now:

http://www.jewelsberry.com/angelfish-charm-pendant-14k-gold-23521.html

Magento version is 1.7.0.0

Please help to understand how it could happen and what can I do to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem appears when you have more than one product with the same url key. Then the numbers (which are in the end of the url) change after every re-index of the 'Catalog Url Rewrite' index.
The best practice is to keep the url key unique per product.

Comment: Thank you! It seems you are right, as I found at least two products with the same URL Key. The thing that concerns me, why everything was good until the point when all this not found errors exploded in huge number:
http://i.imgur.com/QdlhGEM.png

Comment: Unique url_key was not required for Magento 1.7, are you sure you have not updated your installation to more recent version?

Comment: Yes it is not required, but the system can not point the one url to few products, it is not logical. How will magento know which product should it load if in the system there are few products with the same url address?